# What is Java result:3?

Tags: java, java-io

I'm currently learning programming (java) and I've been using a program that runs on command prompt but as an exercise, I've been asked to run it on netbeans and to find out how it can work on it. When I run the program this is the output that I got.

**run:
Please specify a path to a pricing catalogue file
Java Result: 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)**

I've spent several hours on this issue but I was not able to sort it out. Can anybody help me with it please.

Here is the codes.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Grocery {

    private static Catalogue pricingCatalogue;
    private static HashMap<String, Double> inputItemList = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    private static ArrayList<PurchasedProduct> purchasedItemList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if( args.length != 1 )
        {
            System.err.println( "" );
            System.exit( 3 );
        }

        generateCatalogue( args[0] );
        gatherUserInput();
        rateItem();
        printItemizedBill();
    }


    private static void generateCatalogue( String inputFile ) {

        try {

            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines( 
                    Paths.get(inputFile),
                    Charset.defaultCharset() );

            pricingCatalogue = new Catalogue();

            Boolean compareIgnoreCase = false;

            for (String line : lines) {

                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer( line, "|" );

                String productName       = (String)token.nextElement();
                String rateName          = (String)token.nextElement();
                String rateDescr         = (String)token.nextElement();
                Double effectiveQuantity = new Double( (String)token.nextElement() );

                Double effectivePrice;
                String tierPrice;
                Rate newRate;
                Product newProduct;

                if( effectiveQuantity == -1 )
                {

                    tierPrice = (String)token.nextElement();
                    newRate = new Rate( rateName, rateDescr, tierPrice );

                }
                else
                {

                    effectivePrice = new Double( (String)token.nextElement() );
                    newRate = new Rate( rateName, rateDescr, effectiveQuantity, effectivePrice );
                }

                if( true == pricingCatalogue.productIsInCatalogue( productName, compareIgnoreCase ) )
                {

                    pricingCatalogue.addRateToExistingProduct( productName, newRate );
                }
                else
                {

                    newProduct = new Product( productName );
                    newProduct.addRate( newRate );
                    pricingCatalogue.addProduct( newProduct );
                }


            } // end reading input file

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //pricingCatalogue.printCatalogue();
        System.out.println( "Price catalogue loaded sucessfully from [" + inputFile + "]\n" );

    }


    private static void gatherUserInput()
    {

        BufferedReader br           = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        String inStr                = new String();
        String magicWord            = "CHECK OUT";
        Boolean readyToCheckOut     = false;
        Boolean compareIgnoreCase   = false;
        StringTokenizer item_tok    = null;
        String tok                  = null;
        String itemName             = new String();
        Double itemQuantity         = new Double( 0 );

        inputItemList.clear();
        System.out.println( "Please enter an item with quantity in a format like '2 apple'" );
        System.out.println( "When you are done entering item(s), type 'CHECK OUT' to get an itemized bill" );

        while( false == readyToCheckOut )
        {

            System.out.print( ">> ");

            try {
                inStr = br.readLine();
            }catch( IOException ioe ) {
                System.err.println("Failed to read line item");
            }

            item_tok = new StringTokenizer( inStr );

            while(  false == inStr.equals( magicWord )
                    &&
                    true == item_tok.hasMoreTokens() )
            {

                try
                {
                    tok = item_tok.nextElement().toString();
                    itemQuantity = new Double( tok );
                    tok = item_tok.nextElement().toString();
                }
                catch( NumberFormatException nfe )
                {
                    System.err.println( "[" + tok + "] is not something I recognize.  Try something like '2 apple'" );
                    break;
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    System.err.println( "Oops I did not understand that.  Try something like '2 apple'" );
                    break;
                }

                itemName = tok;
                //System.out.println( "--- ITEM [" + itemName + "] QUANTITY [" + ItemQuantity + "]" );

                if( false == pricingCatalogue.productIsInCatalogue( itemName, compareIgnoreCase ) )
                {
                    System.err.println( "Item [" + itemName + "] does not exist in the catalogue" );
                    continue;
                }

                if( true == inputItemList.containsKey( itemName ) ) {

                    itemQuantity = itemQuantity + inputItemList.get( itemName );
                    inputItemList.remove( itemName );
                    inputItemList.put( itemName, itemQuantity );
                }
                else {

                    inputItemList.put( itemName, itemQuantity );
                }
            }

            if( true == inStr.equals( magicWord ) ) {
                readyToCheckOut = true;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println( "inputItemList [" + inputItemList + "]" );

    }

    private static void rateItem()
    {
        purchasedItemList = new ArrayList<PurchasedProduct>();
        Product aProduct;
        Rate bestRate;
        PurchasedProduct pp;
        double purchasedQuantity = 0;

        for( Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : inputItemList.entrySet() )
        {
            String prodName         = entry.getKey();
            Double prodQuantity     = entry.getValue();

            aProduct = pricingCatalogue.getProduct( prodName );

            bestRate = aProduct.getBestRate( prodQuantity );
            purchasedQuantity = bestRate.getEffectiveQuantity();

            pp = new PurchasedProduct( prodName, purchasedQuantity, bestRate );
            purchasedItemList.add( pp );

            prodQuantity = prodQuantity - purchasedQuantity;

            /*
             * Keep finding the best rate for the same product until we
             * have filled the quantity
             */
            while( prodQuantity > 0 )
            {
                bestRate = aProduct.getBestRate( prodQuantity );
                purchasedQuantity = bestRate.getEffectiveQuantity();

                pp = new PurchasedProduct( prodName, purchasedQuantity, bestRate );
                purchasedItemList.add( pp );

                prodQuantity = prodQuantity - purchasedQuantity;
            }

        }
    }


    private static void printItemizedBill()
    {
        PurchasedProduct pp = null;
        Double totalDue = new Double( 0 );
        Double lineTotal = new Double( 0 );

        System.out.println( "\nHere is your invoice:" );

        Iterator ite = purchasedItemList.iterator();
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            pp = (PurchasedProduct)ite.next();
            lineTotal = pp.getPurhcasedCost();
            System.out.format( "%10s%20s%10.2f\n", pp.getPurchasedProductName(), pp.getPurchasedRateDescr(), lineTotal );
            totalDue += lineTotal;
        }

        System.out.format( "\n%10s%20s$%9.2f\n", "TOTAL DUE", "", totalDue );

    }
```

### }

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Catalogue
{

    private ArrayList<Product> productList;

    Catalogue()
    {
        this.productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    /*
     * Returns a boolean if a product exists in the catalogue.  Use the second
     * argument to set whether the comparsion should take case-sensitivity into accoun
     * 
     */
    public boolean productIsInCatalogue( String inProdName, Boolean compareIgnoreCase )
    {

        HashSet<String> currentProductSet = new HashSet<String>();

        /*
         * Get list of pricing product names
         */
        Iterator ite = this.productList.iterator();
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            if( true == compareIgnoreCase )
            {
                currentProductSet.add( ( (Product)ite.next() ).getProductName().toUpperCase() );
            }
            else
            {
                currentProductSet.add( ( (Product)ite.next() ).getProductName() );
            }
        }

        if( true == compareIgnoreCase )
        {
            return currentProductSet.contains( inProdName.toUpperCase() );
        }
        else
        {
            return currentProductSet.contains( inProdName );
        }

    }


    public void addProduct( Product inProduct )
    {
        this.productList.add( inProduct );
    }


    public void addRateToExistingProduct( String inExistingProdName, Rate inRate )
    {
        Iterator ite = this.productList.iterator();

        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            Product currentProd = (Product)ite.next();
            String currentProdName = currentProd.getProductName();

            if( 0 == currentProdName.compareTo( inExistingProdName ) )
            {
                currentProd.addRate( inRate );
                break;
            }

        }

    }


    public Product getProduct( String inExistingProdName )
    {
        Product foundProduct = null;
        Iterator ite = this.productList.iterator();

        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            Product aProduct = (Product)ite.next();
            if( true == aProduct.getProductName().equals( inExistingProdName ) )
            {
                foundProduct = aProduct;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundProduct;

    }

    public void printCatalogue()
    {
        Iterator ite = this.productList.iterator();
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            ( (Product)ite.next() ).printProduct();
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Product
{

    private String productName;
    private HashSet <Rate> productRate;

    Product() 
    {

        this( "N/A" );

    }

    Product( String inProductName ) 
    {

        this.productName = inProductName;
        this.productRate = new HashSet <Rate>();

    }

    /*
     * Add a rate to this product
     */
    public void addRate( Rate inRate ) 
    {

        this.productRate.add( inRate );

    }


    public void printProduct() 
    {

        System.out.println( "*** PRODUCT NAME [" + this.productName + "] ***\n" );

        if( this.productRate.size() > 0 ) 
        {
            Iterator ite = this.productRate.iterator();
            while( ite.hasNext() )
            {
                ((Rate)ite.next()).printRate();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println( "This product does not have rates defined");
        }

        System.out.println( "" );

    }

    public String getProductName()
    {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public Rate getBestRate( Double inQuantity )
    {

        Rate lowestRate = null;
        HashSet <Rate> applicableRate = new HashSet <Rate>();

        Iterator ite = this.productRate.iterator();
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            Rate aRate = (Rate)ite.next();
            if( inQuantity >= aRate.getEffectiveQuantity() )
            {
                applicableRate.add( aRate );
            }
        }

        /*
         * Amongst the available rates, pick the rate with
         * the lowest cost per unit
         */

        ite = applicableRate.iterator();
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {
            Rate appRate = (Rate)ite.next();

            if( null == lowestRate )
            {
                /*
                 * Handle first time entering the loop
                 */
                lowestRate = appRate;
            }

            if( lowestRate.getCostPerUnit() > appRate.getCostPerUnit() )
            {
                lowestRate = appRate;
            }
        }

        return lowestRate;

    }

}
```

---

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class PurchasedProduct
{

    private String  purchasedProdName;
    private double  purchasedQuantity;
    private Rate    purchasedRate;
    private double  purchasedCost;

    PurchasedProduct( String inProdName, double inQuantity, Rate inRate )
    {
        //this.purchasedProdName    = Character.toUpperCase( inProdName.charAt(0) ) + inProdName.substring( 1 );
        this.purchasedProdName  = inProdName;
        this.purchasedQuantity  = inQuantity;
        this.purchasedRate      = inRate;
        this.purchasedCost      = this.getCost();
    }

    public String getPurchasedProductName()
    {
        return this.purchasedProdName;
    }

    public String getPurchasedRateDescr()
    {
        return this.purchasedRate.getRateDescr();
    }

    public double getPurhcasedCost()
    {
        return this.purchasedCost;
    }

    private double getCost()
    {
        double lineCost = 0;

        if( false == this.purchasedRate.isTiered() )
        {
            lineCost = this.purchasedRate.getEffectivePrice();
        }
        else
        {
            lineCost = this.purchasedRate.getTierPrice( new Double( this.purchasedQuantity ) );
        }

        return round( lineCost, 2 );
    }

    private double round( double value, int places ) 
    {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/*
 * Rate class represents the detail on how to rate a specific product
 * A product may have many rates
 */
public class Rate
{

    private String rateName;            
    private String rateDescr;           // bill invoice display
    private double effectiveQuantity;   // the total quantity applicable to take advantage of this rate
    private double effectivePrice;      // the total price applicable
    private double costPerUnit;         // average cost per unit
    private ArrayList<Map> tiers;       // ONLY applicable if this is tierd pricing

    Rate()
    {
        this( "N/A", "N/A", 0, 0 );
    }

    /*
     * Non-tier rate constructor
     */
    Rate( String inRateName, String inRateDesc, double inEffQ, double inEffPr )
    {
        this.rateName = inRateName;
        this.rateDescr = inRateDesc;
        this.effectiveQuantity = inEffQ;
        this.effectivePrice = inEffPr;
        this.tiers = new ArrayList<Map>();

        this.costPerUnit = this.getCostPerUnit();           
    }

    /*
     * Tier rate constructor
     */
    Rate( String inRateName, String inRateDesc, String tier_val )
    {
        this.rateName = inRateName;
        this.rateDescr = inRateDesc;
        this.effectiveQuantity = -1; // this is calculated later in getCostPerUnit
        this.effectivePrice = -1;
        this.tiers = new ArrayList<Map>();

        /*
         * Example tier_val "1-1,0.50,1;2-2,0.50,0.50"
         * Each tier is separated by ';'
         * A token within a tier is operated by ','
         */
        StringTokenizer more_tiers = new StringTokenizer( tier_val, ";" );

        while( more_tiers.hasMoreTokens() )
        {
            StringTokenizer tier_detail = new StringTokenizer( (String)more_tiers.nextElement(), "," );
            Map<String, Double> tier_map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

            /*
             * First token is the min to max quantity e.g. 1-1 or 1-5
             */
            String[] minMaxVal = tier_detail.nextElement().toString().split("-");

            tier_map.put( "MIN", new Double( minMaxVal[0] ) );
            tier_map.put( "MAX", new Double( minMaxVal[1] ) );

            /*
             * Second token is the quantity price per unit so 1.50 mean charge each unit for 1.50
             */
            tier_map.put( "PRICE", new Double( (String)tier_detail.nextElement() ) );

            /*
             * Third token is the discount scale, e.g 1 means 100% no discount and 0.5 means 50% discount
             */
            tier_map.put( "SCALE", new Double( (String)tier_detail.nextElement() ) );

            tiers.add( tier_map );
        }

        this.costPerUnit = this.getCostPerUnit();

    }

    public String getRateDescr()
    {
        return this.rateDescr;
    }

    public double getEffectiveQuantity()
    {
        return this.effectiveQuantity;
    }

    public double getEffectivePrice()
    {
        return this.effectivePrice;
    }

    public Boolean isTiered()
    {
        return ( this.effectivePrice == -1 );
    }

    /*
     * Calculate the total cost with the input quantity
     */
    public double getTierPrice( double inQuantity )
    {
        Iterator ite        = this.tiers.iterator();

        Double min          = new Double( 0 );
        Double max          = new Double( 0 );
        Double price        = new Double( 0 );
        Double scale        = new Double( 0 );

        Double total_cost   = new Double( 0 );
        Double total_quan   = new Double( 0 );
        Double tierMaxQ     = new Double( 0 );

        Double toRateQuan  = new Double( inQuantity );

        /*
         * Step through each tier
         */
        while( ite.hasNext() )
        {

            Map tier_map = (Map)ite.next();

            min     = (Double)tier_map.get( "MIN" );
            max     = (Double)tier_map.get( "MAX" );
            price   = (Double)tier_map.get( "PRICE" );
            scale   = (Double)tier_map.get( "SCALE" );

            /*
             * Get the tier applicable units
             */
            tierMaxQ = max - min + 1;

            if( 0 >= toRateQuan )
            {
                break;
            }
            else if( toRateQuan >= tierMaxQ )
            {
                /*
                 * The incoming to-to-rated quantity is greater than
                 * the tier total units.  Rate it with the
                 * maximum units in this tier
                 */
                total_cost = total_cost + ( tierMaxQ * price * scale );
                toRateQuan = toRateQuan - tierMaxQ;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * The incoming to-be-rated quantity is less than
                 * the tier total units.  Rate it with the to-be-rated
                 * quantity
                 */
                total_cost = total_cost + ( toRateQuan * price * scale );
                break;
            }

        }

        return total_cost;

    }

    /*
     * Calculate the 'average' cost per unit
     * 
     * For a non-tiered rate, the average cost is price over quantity
     * 
     * For a tiered rate, we calculate each tier cost, add them up and
     * divide by the total quantity to get the average cost
     * 
     */
    public double getCostPerUnit()
    {

        if( false == this.isTiered() )
        {
            /*
             * Simple pricing; individual or bulk
             */
            return ( this.effectivePrice / this.effectiveQuantity );
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * Tier pricing.  Calculate the total cost then divide by the quantity to
             * get the average cost
             */
            Iterator ite        = this.tiers.iterator();

            Double min          = new Double( 0 );
            Double max          = new Double( 0 );
            Double price        = new Double( 0 );
            Double scale        = new Double( 0 );

            Double total_cost   = new Double( 0 );
            Double total_quan   = new Double( 0 );
            Double costPerUnit  = new Double( 0 );

            while( ite.hasNext() )
            {

                Map tier_map = (Map)ite.next();

                min     = (Double)tier_map.get( "MIN" );
                max     = (Double)tier_map.get( "MAX" );
                price   = (Double)tier_map.get( "PRICE" );
                scale   = (Double)tier_map.get( "SCALE" );

                if( 0 >= ( max - min + 1 ) )
                {
                    break;
                }

                total_quan = total_quan + ( max - min + 1 );
                total_cost = total_cost + ( ( max - min + 1 ) * price * scale );

            }

            this.effectiveQuantity = total_quan;
            costPerUnit = total_cost / total_quan;

            return costPerUnit;
        }
    }

    /*
     * DEBUG
     */
    public void printRate()
    {
        System.out.println( "\tRATE NAME [" + this.rateName + "]" );
        System.out.println( "\tRATE DESC [" + this.rateDescr + "]" );
        System.out.println( "\tQUANTITY [" + this.effectiveQuantity + "]" );
        System.out.println( "\tCOST PER UNIT [" + this.costPerUnit + "]" );

        if( false == this.isTiered() )
        {
            System.out.println( "\tPRICE [" + this.effectivePrice + "]" );
        }
        else
        {
            int num_tiers = this.tiers.size();
            for( int i = 0; i < num_tiers; ++i )
            {
                System.out.println( "\t--- TIER [" + ( i + 1 ) + "]" );
                System.out.println( "\t\t    --- MIN      [" + this.tiers.get( i ).get( "MIN") + "]" );
                System.out.println( "\t\t    --- MAX      [" + this.tiers.get( i ).get( "MAX") + "]" );
                System.out.println( "\t\t    --- PRICE    [" + this.tiers.get( i ).get( "PRICE") + "]" );
                System.out.println( "\t\t    --- SCALE    [" + this.tiers.get( i ).get( "SCALE") + "]" );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "\n\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting a stacktrace? Can you post that?

Comment: Are you passing in any arguments? If the argument count is not equal to 1 then it will generate an error code of 3.

Comment: That is very odd. Your code does not contain such a string, and none of the imported classes would refer to "a pricing catalogue". EDIT: You are using a class `Catalogue` which you haven't shown us, the error might well be generated there.

Comment: No i am not getting a stack trace. Here is what I got           run:
Please specify a path to a pricing catalogue file
Java Result: 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You need to pass in an input file of your catalog on the command line.

Comment: Sorry I've added the missing classes in the post

Answer (score 1):

This

```
System.exit( 3 );
```

Causes your process to return (in Java parlance it exits) with a value to the operating system. It's equivalent to the `int` returned by `main` in c and c++. On unix style systems you can access the return value with

```
echo $?
```

It looks like you are supposed to call this program with a file-path to some catalogue as the first argument (`args[0]`), otherwise it exits.